# Pass multiple arguments to model.bind in aurelia

Tags: binding, aurelia

Is it possible to pass multiple arguments to `model.bind`? Something along the lines `model.bind="{car: carObject, factory: factoryObject}"` ?

I would like to use it in a snippet like

```
    <div class="column">
        <compose
            view="./car.html"
            view-model="../../view-models/cars"
            model.bind="{car: $parent.$parent.car, factoryIndex: $index}">
        </compose>
    </div>
```

and in the VM to handle them like

```
public activate(car, factoryIndex) {
    this.data = car;
    this.factoryIndex= factoryIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are binding your model you are creating an object that contains both a property for car and factoryIndex - so if you use it like this in your activate function it should work:

```
public activate(data) {
    this.data = data.car;
    this.factoryIndex = data.factoryIndex;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks